# route l2tp server to openvpn client

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, openvpn, route, l2tp

i configured l2tp/ipsec server on ubuntu

also i installed openvpn client on this server

i need when l2tp client connect to this server traffic forward to openvpn and client get openvpn server ip address:

( for example if l2tp server public ip is 1.2.3.4 and openvpn server is 1.2.3.5 when l2tp client connect to server get 1.2.3.5 public ip address )

l2tp client <--> l2tp server <-- openvpn client --> openvpn server

l2tp clients subnet: 192.168.42.0/24

openvpn client: 
tun0: inet 10.8.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.8.0.2

my iptables and route:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Tue Dec  3 16:45:27 2019
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [246:15683]
:INPUT ACCEPT [177:11140]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [58:3868]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [58:3868]
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.42.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Dec  3 16:45:27 2019
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Tue Dec  3 16:45:27 2019
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [168:8188]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4628:1611471]
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 500,4500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1701 -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp+ -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.42.0/24 -d 192.168.42.0/24 -i ppp+ -o ppp+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Dec  3 16:45:27 2019


root@softeth:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         static.160.93.2 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
static.93.169.4 static.160.93.2 255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
95.217.93.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

thanks